# Python script outputing last raw only

Tags: python-3.x

I am a python beginner and started with simple script to assign the appropriate amino acid to its codon in a tab delimited file as shown below. But the script only print the last raw. Please help if any one knows the answer.

## the script

```
geneticCode = { 'TTT': 'F',
                'TTC': 'F',
                'TTA': 'L',
                'TTG': 'L',
                'TCT': 'S',
                # many more...
               }
        
def aa (codon):
    return (geneticCode.get(codon, "x")
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    with open("dna.txt",'r') as f:
        for i,line in enumerate(f):
            
            if i==0: 
                print(line.strip("\n")+"\t"+'aa')
                continue
            fields=line.split('\t')
            codon =fields[1]        
            amino= aa(codon)
            print(line.strip("\n")+"\t"+ str(amino))
```

Thanks for the help in advance...

Comment: please show what's in dna.txt

Comment: dna.txt contains 2 columns:second column called "codon"
1 TTC
2 TTT

Answer (score 0):

if you print `codon`, you can see that `codon` contains `\n`. So you can 
change `fields=line.split('\t')` to `fields=line.strip('\n').split('\t')`